# How can i fix the mscorlib error?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2017, mscorlib

I have been getting this kind of error on my project which has cost me valuable time. I don't know what to do at this moment. I have tried reference `MScorlib` with a higher version and the problem persist. Please look at my stack trace.

> System.NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.LanguageServices.Implementation.VisualStudioAddMetadataReferenceCodeActionOperationFactoryWorkspaceService.AddMetadataReferenceOperation.Apply(Workspace workspace,CancellationToken cancellationToken)
>      at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ProcessOperationsAsync()
>      at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.CodeActions.CodeActionEditHandlerService.ApplyAsync()
>      at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.InvokeWorkerAsync()
>      at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Editor.Implementation.Suggestions.SuggestedAction.<>c__DisplayClass19_0.b__0()
>      at async Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Extensions.IExtensionManagerExtensions.PerformActionAsync()

The original error says

> you must reference mscorlib version 4.0.0.0, culture=natural,
>   puclickeytoken=etc.

How do I solve this?

Comment: Can you provide extra context information? Visual Studio version, when does it appear (e.g. when it should propose autocomplete options) etc.

Comment: Judging from the callstack, it looks like you're invoking a Suggested Action (aka Lightbulb) in VS, and it's throwing this error.  Is that correct?

Comment: I am using vs 2017rc... the red error line appears underneath the method am calling which is from another project referenced

Comment: any solution for above error, because i have face in  same issue ..please suggest me if any solution

Answer (score 3):

Delete all files from **Debug folder**, then right click on ur **Solution** and **Clean Solution** and then **Rebuild** solution,

Comment: the problem is still there

Comment: Thanks for providing the location to the Debug folder, super useful! :D

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried deleting the VS cache

C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\
C:\Users\\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\ComponentModelCache

and run devenv as admin.

if above doesn't fix it, check out following 2 resources,
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/146fbb05-ab92-4a31-a29e-ed85599e12b7/visual-c-2015-rc-compiler-could-not-be-created?forum=vssetup

http://vimvq1987.com/2016/07/fixing-visual-studio-2015-update-3/

Comment: am using vs 2017rc.